# How can I generate an Android Keystore from a key.pk8 and certificate.pem?

Tags: android, eclipse, keystore

So today I finally update my SDK to 22.0.0 however this creates an error in the AndroidManifest.xml for `android:debuggable="false"` which means I can no longer externally sign and zipalign my own apks.

I have been signing using my own key.pk8 and certificate.pem, however eclipse ADT requires a keystore.

Does anyone know a way to either build a keystore using my already generated key or find some way around this?

Comment: You can import it using keytool. Take a look at: $keytool -help

Comment: Ok So I've used keytool to create a new keystore and shift the certificate into it. However when I try to use the keystore in ADT to try to sign an application I can see my key and enter my password, however nothing happens. No movement forward, but also no error. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi sorry for delay to reply, i was off. Try to list all stuff from you keystore to be sure that it is there: keytool -v -list -keystore [keystore_path]

Comment: @betorcs Thanks for your help, I've managed to fix the problem, and you can see the solution I used below.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Ok, So I eventually managed to solve the problem.

I downloaded openssl for windows from [here](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)

Keytool can be found at `E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin`

Then using keytool and openssl managed to build the key.pk8 and certificate.pem into a keystore entry

```
openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -nocrypt -in key.pk8 -out key.pem

openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.pem -inkey key.pem -out platform.p12 -password pass:android -name mykey

keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass password -destkeystore .keystore -srckeystore platform.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass android

keytool -list -v -keystore .keystore
```

The last step is just to verify that the key has been added to the keystore.

Comment: In first step, if the input pk8 file has a password, remove the `-nocrypt` option, openssl will prompt password input.

Comment: @SamShute: From where did you get the .pk8 and .pem certificates? Can I search and find them on my android device's OS files?

Comment: I have the .pk8 and .pem files. I have a .keystore file. what is platform.p12 here??

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for an answer, This is one script you can run to create a keystore from .pem and .pk8 files.

***Note : Don't forget to modify file names and password for your keystore before running the bash script.***

[Bash script to create keystore quickly](https://gist.github.com/Mirochiu/c606e5d721b5f7b29b5773b32d2c028e)